# Issue with accessing azure B2C custom page layout hosted in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, msal-angular, azure-ad-b2c

My team is having a 'random' issue to where certain users are getting the error below when trying to run one of our b2c userflows.  The userflow works 95% of the time, but 'randomly' a user (existing or new) will get this issue and be unable to sign in/register until the issue resolves itself.

The frontend is using msal-angular with the login type of redirect.

We are using the login function outlined in the example repo provided by MS:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-v2-samples/angular11-b2c-sample/src/app/app.component.ts

AADB2C90047: The resource '[MY URL HERE]' contains script errors preventing it from being loaded.

[Error message stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lha4.png)

There were also a few posts talking about needing to enable javascript on the flow. That has also been done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/24450/how-to-resolve-aadb2c90047-the-resource-httpslocal.html

[Javascript Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW6R2.png)

I also see a few pointed back at CORS issues.  I have enabled the allow-origin: * to my cloudfront and s3 set up in AWS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/236653/azure-ad-b2c-tutorial-for-customize-ui-causes-a-sc.html

[CORS set up in terraform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHQr.png)